# Can persistent data only be achieved using session variables?

Tags: php, session, checkout

I'm trying to figure out the one-page checkout system at oldnavy.ca.

If you could take the time to throw some stuff in the cart and mess around to see what it is like, I would greatly appreciate it.

What confuses me is that refreshing the page saves the current state of the process. So, if you create your sign in name and add your shipping address it will be there if you hit refresh.

Reading many articles it sounds like using session variables to store a lot of data is not considered good programming. Now, is storing form data, like shipping info etc... considered "a lot" of data?

I'm just curious to know how they implemented this cart system, because it's used everywhere and I don't want to be reluctant to use session variables if it works.

Maybe there are alternatives in use?

Thanks

Comment: They're not necessarily storing everything in the SESSION - they might be storing a unique ID in there, and adding everything to the database instead. There's no real way to be sure how they're dealing with it, though - it's the same from the end user's point of view.

Comment: would that be more efficient to store it directly to the database? They will have to remove that data from the database when the session expires, manually.

Comment: If they're doing that, they'll have something that runs regularly and cleans up sessions that haven't been updated in a while - disk space is cheap, and running a batch job in the middle of the night won't be noticed by most users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no hard and fast answer for this, only guidelines.

If you use standard PHP sessions, they're saved in plain files on the server's disk, one per active session. This also means upon each pageload, the relevant session file is read from disk into memory. How much is "too much" depends on many factors...

- how long does it take to read the file from disk into memory?
- disk caching can prevent a physical disk access each time, but the larger the files the fewer of them will be in disk cache
- how much memory is the data taking up in RAM?
- how long does it take to serialize the data and write it back to disk?
- how many concurrent users do you have that require PHP to read from and write to disk all the time?
- how long are sessions active, i.e. how many session files will be littered around the disk before they are garbage collected?

For the typical small web shop (not Amazon size), the answer is that file based sessions are typically perfectly fine. You'll probably be storing some tens of kilobytes max in each file, which is plenty to keep a user's address data and shopping basket. You'll hardly run into problems with this.

Alternatively there are simply other session handlers. You can keep them in a memcache store or a database, which alleviates many of the file based issues. Evaluate which solution fits your situation better.

Comment: so the alternative is to save the session ID and have all associated data in the database? The next question I have is how would you remove that data when the session expires? My shopping cart will be low volume so Sessions might be easier for me.

Comment: A session is simply a cookie with a unique ID and *some* server-side mechanism that stores data somewhere that is associated with that id. If you want to use a non-file based session storage, look at the [`save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler). Removing the data is part of the garbage collection cycle of the chosen session handler.